# Android Emulator 2.0 freeze with GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator

The Android Emulator 2.0 freezes some time after GPS is enabled. 
The Android part completely freezes, the "control GUI" panel still works (but obliviously no effect to Home etc).
adb lists the emulator but no response for adb logcat etc.

The emulator must be closed with ctrl-alt-del. Next freeze comes faster. Instead of occurring within a minute, it occurs within tens of seconds. The PC must be rebooted to get back to a minute.

I want GPS and pressure sensors so GENYmotion and Visual Studio emulators are not an option.

Windows 10 Pro 64bit (before/after Anniversary Edition)
8GB RAM, Intel i5-3570, 30GB available on the Windows disk
Intel HAXM 6.0.3
Occurs for x86, x86_64, arm. Primarily been using Android 7.0 emulator, similar for older versions.
Also occurs with fresh AVD
Default settings for emulators (have tried deactivation multi-core, give more RAM etc)
AVD launched from AS 2.1.2 and 2.2beta1
Nothing seen in system logs, AS logs though: C:\Users\.AndroidStudioPreview2.2\system\log\threadDumps-20160814-103215-AI-145.3128856\freeze-20160814-120115-75\threadDump-20160814-120226.txt Cannot make out something from the logs.

Comment: Created issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231327

Comment: Reproduced by Google so bug

Answer (score 0):

Google has released an update and closed the issue. 
Working for me.